# Kinect sdk v1.5 face tracking by using XNA 4.0 Framework of C#

Tags: xna, kinect

I am a new kinect developer and going to develop some application related to face tracking by using kinect v1.5 and XNA Framework in c# platform.

I can successfully get the face points and rectangle points to display in the screen by using the kinect sdk and Basic Effect of XNA 3D drawing.

However, What i want is to get back exactly the same color pixel of the user's face so that I can get mapping of the user's real face to a model.

Is there anybody that can help to answer my question?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways you can achieve this would be by using the RGB (colour) video stream and capturing a still. You can then use C# to enumerate through the X/Y axis of this image to get the colour if required.

The more effcient way however would be to use this still as the texture and "wrap" the 3D model you are creating using it. There is an example provided with the Kinect SDK which does something similar, the sample is called Face Tracking 3D - WPF. I would encourage you to use this as your base porting to XNA and work from there.

Comment: I have studied the example of the Face Tracking 3D - WPF and can get the current user face by get the current texture from the RGB Video stream! Thank you very much!